# Calculating age over multiple dataframes based on name of dataframe

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I was wondering if someone here can help me with a `lapply` question.

Every month,  data are extracted and the data frames are named according to the date extracted (`01-08-2019`,`01-09-2019`,`01-10-2019` etc). The contents of each data frame are similar to the example below:

```
01-09-2019

ID   DOB 
3    01-07-2019
5    01-06-2019
7    01-05-2019
8    01-09-2019

01-10-2019

ID   DOB 
2    01-10-2019
5    01-06-2019
8    01-09-2019
9    01-02-2019
```

As the months roll on, there are more data sets being downloaded.

I am wanting to calculate the ages of people in each of the data sets based on the date the data was extracted - so in essence, the age would be the date difference between the data frame name and the `DOB` variable.

```
01-09-2019

ID   DOB          AGE(months)
3    01-07-2019   2
5    01-06-2019   3
7    01-05-2019   4
8    01-09-2019   0

01-10-2019

ID   DOB          AGE(months)
2    01-10-2019   0   
5    01-06-2019   4
8    01-09-2019   1
9    01-02-2019   8
```

I was thinking of putting all of the data frames together in a list (as there are a lot) and then using `lapply` to calculate age across all data frames. How do I go about calculating the difference between a data frame name and a column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I may suggest a slightly differen approach: It might make more sense to compress your list into a single data frame before calculating the ages. Given your data looks something like this, i.e. it is a list of data frames, where the list element names are the dates of access:

```r
$`01-09-2019`
# A tibble: 4 x 2
     ID DOB       
  <dbl> <date>    
1     3 2019-07-01
2     5 2019-06-01
3     7 2019-05-01
4     8 2019-09-01

$`01-10-2019`
# A tibble: 4 x 2
     ID DOB       
  <dbl> <date>    
1     2 2019-10-01
2     5 2019-06-01
3     8 2019-09-01
4     9 2019-02-01
```

You can call `bind_rows` first with parameter `.id = "date_extracted"` to turn your list into a data frame, and then calculate age in months.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

tib <- bind_rows(tib_list, .id = "date_extracted") %>% 
    mutate(date_extracted = dmy(date_extracted),
           DOB = dmy(DOB),
           age_months = month(date_extracted) - month(DOB)
           )

#### OUTPUT ####
# A tibble: 8 x 4
  date_extracted    ID DOB        age_months
  <date>         <dbl> <date>          <dbl>
1 2019-09-01         3 2019-07-01          2
2 2019-09-01         5 2019-06-01          3
3 2019-09-01         7 2019-05-01          4
4 2019-09-01         8 2019-09-01          0
5 2019-10-01         2 2019-10-01          0
6 2019-10-01         5 2019-06-01          4
7 2019-10-01         8 2019-09-01          1
8 2019-10-01         9 2019-02-01          8
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with `lapply` as well but we can also use `Map` in this case to iterate over list and their names after adding all the dataframes in a list. In base R,

```
Map(function(x, y) {
 x$DOB <- as.Date(x$DOB)
 transform(x, age = as.integer(format(as.Date(y), "%m")) - 
                    as.integer(format(x$DOB, "%m")))
}, list_df, names(list_df))


#$`01-09-2019`
#  ID        DOB age
#1  3 0001-07-20   2
#2  5 0001-06-20   3
#3  7 0001-05-20   4
#4  8 0001-09-20   0

#$`01-10-2019`
#  ID        DOB age
#1  2 0001-10-20   0
#2  5 0001-06-20   4
#3  8 0001-09-20   1
#4  9 0001-02-20   8
```

---

We can also do the same in `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

purrr::imap(list_df, ~.x %>% mutate(age = month(.y) - month(DOB)))
```

**data**

```
list_df <- list(`01-09-2019` = structure(list(ID = c(3L, 5L, 7L, 8L), 
DOB = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("01-05-2019", "01-06-2019", 
"01-07-2019", "01-09-2019"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -4L)), `01-10-2019` = structure(list(ID = c(2L, 5L, 8L, 9L), 
DOB = structure(c(4L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("01-02-2019", 
"01-06-2019", "01-09-2019", "01-10-2019"), class = "factor")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L)))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's bad practice to use dates and numbers as dataframe names consider prefix the date with an "x" as shown below in this base R solution:

```
df_list <- list(x01_09_2019 = `01-09-2019`, x01_10_2019 = `01-10-2019`)

df_list <- mapply(cbind, "report_date" = names(df_list), df_list, SIMPLIFY = F)

df_list <- lapply(df_list, function(x){

  x$report_date <- as.Date(gsub("_", "-", gsub("x", "", x$report_date)), "%d-%m-%Y")

  x$Age <- x$report_date - x$DOB

  return(x)

  }

)
```

Data:

```
`01-09-2019` <- structure(list(ID = c(3, 5, 7, 8),
                               DOB = structure(c(18078, 18048, 18017, 18140), class = "Date")),
                          class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

`01-10-2019` <- structure(list(ID = c(2, 5, 8, 9),
               DOB = structure(c(18170, 18048, 18140, 17928), class = "Date")),
          class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```